# xamarin forms : post requests result 500 Internal server error

Tags: iis, xamarin.forms, asp.net-web-api2, windows-server-2016

When I post a request from xamarin forms app to my web service I just get the following result: "500 Internal server error" but when I do the same request using postman It works.

I googled and read many posts about this type of errors but without any result to my problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

My code in xamarin forms is:

```
var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
HttpResponseMessage hrm = await _client.PostAsync(RestURL, content);
```

Comment: An HTTP 500 error means something is wrong on the server. However, seeing that it works from Postman, it must be your input causing the error. Still, you would probably have to look into the server logs and application output there (if possible) to see what the actual error is.

Comment: I'm using the same input in xamarin.forms and postman (Copy & Paste),I have looked in the server logs and there is no errors registered with my service name.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. maybe it helps other ones.

There was a mistake in my previous code, so I rewrite it with this one:

```
 HttpResponseMessage hrm = await _client.PostAsync(RestURL, new StringContent(content, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```